# Ошибка при объявлении класса

Tags: c++, ооп, файловая-система

Есть два заголовочных файла task.h и engine.h в первом объявляется класс Pyramid

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

using namespace std;

class Pyramid {
private:
   Polygon *polygons;
public:
   Pyramid(const char* file_name);
   ~Pyramid();
};

#endif
```

Во втором объявляется класс Polygon

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

class Polygon {
private:
   int count;
   double** coordinate; 

public:
   Polygon(int count, double **arr);
   ~Polygon();
};

#endif
```

В cpp файлах написаны реализации этих классов. При компиляции появляется ошибка **error: 'Polygon' does not name a type**. Понимаю, что проблема заключается в создании экземпляра класса Polygon в объявлении класса Pyramid. Не знаю как решить данную проблему.

Подключение обоих заголовочных файлов происходит в main.cpp

```
#include "graphics.h"
#include "engine.h"
#include "task.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробовал, отключить заголовочный файл engine.h в main, и включил его в task.cpp, проблема осталась.

Comment: Скорее всего вы не в том порядке включаете, как указали. В любом случае, попробуйте перед объявлением `Pyramid` написать `class Polygon;`. В следующий раз указывайте все точно, включая место в коде, на которое ругается компилятор. Вы же даже файл не указали, не говоря уж о строке...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**engine.hpp**

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

class Polygon {
private:
   int count;
   double** coordinate; 

public:
   Polygon(int, double**);
   ~Polygon();
};

#endif
```

**task.hpp**

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

class Polygon;

class Pyramid {
   Polygon* polygons;

public:
   Pyramid(const char*);
   ~Pyramid();
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "engine.hpp"
#include "task.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
   return 0;
}
```